# Laravel Application showing NGNIX 502 Bad gateway in Porter.run Platform

Tags: laravel, docker, nginx, networking

I am trying to run a Laravel project on Porter.run platform,
this is my DockerFile

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:latest

COPY . .

# Image config
ENV SKIP_COMPOSER 1
ENV WEBROOT /var/www/html/public
ENV PHP_ERRORS_STDERR 1
ENV RUN_SCRIPTS 1
ENV REAL_IP_HEADER 1

# Laravel config
ENV APP_ENV production
ENV APP_DEBUG false
ENV LOG_CHANNEL stderr

# Allow composer to run as root
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

CMD ["/start.sh"]
```

It show 502  bad gateway Error
What could be the probelm?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your Nginx configuration. What does your Docker Logs say when you try and run it locally?

Comment: I have updated the question to include the current Nginx configuration